# Why put a reverse proxy in front of a WSGI server?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, wsgi

A typical configuration for deploying a WSGI application includes a WSGI server (such as uWSGI or Gunicorn) behind a general-purpose web server (like nginx) that acts as a reverse proxy. One major reason I know for having a reverse proxy is to serve static files efficiently. Are there any other reasons?

Suppose my application involves only Python code and doesn’t care about static content. Why would I want the reverse proxy in this case? uWSGI and Gunicorn each already provide an asynchronous HTTP server capable of interfacing with the clients.

Are there any practical cases where I would be better off exposing the WSGI HTTP server directly to the outside world?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- you have more config-options with a full-blown reverse - proxy like

  - rewrite
  - locations
  - server
  - https
  - header-cleanup
  - expires
  - gzip
  - ....
- you can do loadbalancing
- you can use proxy_cache
- you can implement custom error-pages, even when your app-servers are down
- you can have a WAF implemented
- you can (sometimes) hotpatch against vulnerabilities

**BONUSPOINT**

- you can impress clients with 100.000 requests/second (on average hardware) with the following setup (nginx):

.

```
location /perftest/ {
    return 200;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Additional Advantages to using a reverse proxy.**

Other benefits can be gained that MAY be of benefit to you.

- You can hide information from the internet (web server version, app server, database server, api)
- You can implement multiple web server technologies behind one domain (Linux tomcat + Windows IIS etc)
- You can terminate https/SSL connections and map them to internal http services.
- You can centralise all logging.
- You can centralise all DDOS prevention
- You can Implement identity management from the web server tier.

Security Advantages

- Internal server hiding as above.
- You can router/firewall your internal app server servers, and database servers from the internet without resorting to software firewalls on the host (called a DMZ).
- You can protect a server that is not immediatly fixable from known problems (web application firewall) or known attack patterns.