# Is a reverse proxy useful behind a load balancer and IPS

Tags: security, firewall, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, ips

We have a Web infrastructure with a farm of Web Servers.
They are behind a loadbalancer which does SSL offload.
We also have a IPS and obviously a set of firewalls.

Now, for security reason we have been asked to look into the possibility of adding a reverse proxy.
I insist this is for security reason only as we are not planning to use any caching.

My question is:
Is it worth the effort? Is there any added value to an additional layer and if yes would it justify the time spent?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/536144/why-put-a-reverse-proxy-in-front-of-a-wsgi-server

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver is (pre-)forking or uses light weight processes (threads) then using an event based proxy (e.g. ATS, nginx, NOT varnish) in front gives a lot of protection against sloloris type attacks. But in the absence of any caching (or DOS attacks) it's going to slow down your traffic.

Why so anti caching?

Comment: Caching was just not part of the original scope, I am happy to add it if not having it penalise the performance.

Comment: update--Caching was just not part of the original scope, I am happy to add it if not having it penalise the performance significantly. Overall I had the feeling that the reverse-proxy would be redundant with the LB+IPS.
I should add that our webservers are in the DMZ only accessible by the LoadBalancer